# playOrm basic setup + playOrm maturity

Tags: playorm

1. I want to do a POC and I would like a basic example of using playOrm. How do I create a basic project using eclipse and how do I configure the connection to Cassandra?
2. How mature is playOrm today? Do you recommend it's use in production, knowing I will enter with a basic setup in production in three months from now?

Comment: I just answered a similar getting started question here Getting Started with PlayORM
maturity question....PlayOrm has 62 tests already and we are using it in production.