# How to index inside a partition?

Tags: playorm

In playOrm readme, the following query is listed:

//First, on the Activity.java, you will have a NoSqlQuery like so
@NoSqlQuery(name="queryByValue", query="PARTITIONS a(:partId) SELECT a FROM TABLE as a "+
                        "WHERE a.price > :value and a.numShares < 10")

I understood how easy is it to select the right partition to query on, but the clause "a.price > :value" is selecting something on a CF column. Even if I have few rows inside the partition, wouldn't I need an index for this column? How to create it using playOrm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, sometimes takes me 1 day to respond.

```
PARTITIONS a(:partId) SELECT a FROM TABLE as a "+ "WHERE a.price > :value and a.numShares < 10"
```

When you say "right partition", I assume you mean correct partition rather than left/right.  The above is written in JQL so I can write part of the entity based on that query as

```
MyEntity {
  @NoSqlIndexed
  private BigDecimal price;
  @NoSqlIndexed
  private int numShares;

  //other fields
}
```

The annotations tell playOrm to index price and numShares fields.  Currently you can only use fields in the WHERE clause if they are indexed....this may change in the future as we add more features.

so you do NOT need to create a partition, PlayOrm will do that.  To create an index later, the current way is you add @NoSqlIndexed to an existing entity and you map/reduce reading the row and then saving the row.....we are working to fix that so you can just run our map/reduce jobs to re-index something across the cluster.

Also in relation to your question that some people closed [playOrm basic setup + playOrm maturity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569925/playorm-basic-setup-playorm-maturity)

which I think was valid

1. I just answered a similar getting started question here [Getting Started with PlayORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574027/getting-started-with-playorm/12583232#12583232)
2. maturity question....PlayOrm has 62 tests already and we are using it in production.

later,
Dean