# Getting Started with PlayORM

Tags: playorm

Is there any sort of "How-To" for playORM? I'm just starting to work with it, and haven't been able to get any farther than importing the Ant build file into Eclipse. I didn't see anything like a readme in the unpacked tarball, besides a file in the `examples/` directory that says "This is the examples directory" and a feature list in the main directory. Is there anything I can look at to get started using playORM, or is it just meant to be trial and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very sorry, we are working on documentation.  Until then, here are the steps

1. check out playOrm
2. run build or build.bat to generate parser code
3. import into eclipse
4. right click on the com.alvazan.test folder and choose run As -> Junit test (all tests should pass)
5. Modify FactorySingleton.java (change IN_MEMORY to CASSANDRA and change seeds if desired)
6. repeat running the test suite again if you like so you can play with
7. NOW that all tests passing and you know that is all and well, EVERY test is the perfect example and the bootstrap is FactorySingleton so you can look at it's code to get started

LAST NOTE: Your jar requires a file nosql.Persistence or PlayOrm(just like hibernate) will not scan your jar for classes.

later,
Dean

Comment: That sounds easy enough, you should drop that into the Readme while you're working on the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is now available at https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki